# Can cut keep just the first letter after a comma and whitespace?

Tags: cut-command

I have input that looks like this:

```
Austin, Ashley D
Bender, Isaiah J
```

Here I am trying to cut the first name till the "," and then add the first letter of second name.

For example, the above two will be Austina and Benderi. Can anybody help please.

Answer (score 1):

You've expressed interest in solving this with `cut`. There should be a way to do it with [pipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) and some combination of [`cut`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/cut.1.html), [`tr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/tr.1.html), and (maybe) [`paste`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/paste.1.html). But especially since you're modifying the case of the initial (e.g., the leading "A" in Ashley becomes the trailing "a" in "Austina"), it's easier to use something more verstatile than `cut`. I suggest **a Perl one-liner**, which could be this or something like it, depending primarily on what characters you want to allow in names:

```bash
perl -wpe 's/^(\w+),\s*(\w).*/$1\L$2/' file
```

That runs the Perl interpreter, with warnings enabled (`-w`), reading input line-by-line, executing a script on each line and printing the result (`-p`), and taking its script from the next command-line argument (`-e`). The script itself, `s/^(\w+),\s*(\w).*/$1\L$2/`, which I [quote](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) with [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) so the shell doesn't perform its own [expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) on it, consists of a `s/pattern/replacement/` expression, which matches its input to *pattern* and replaces the match with *replacement*.

In the [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), `^(\w+),\s*(\w).*`:

- [`^`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) matches the beginning of a line.
- `(\w+)` matches one or more ([`+`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)) word characters ([`\w`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html), see below), and captures them ([`(` `)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)) into the first capture group.
- `,` matches itself literally.
- `\s*` matches zero or more ([`*`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)) whitespace characters ([`\s`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)).
- `(\w)` matches exactly one word character ([`\w`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html), see below), and captures it ([`(` `)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)) into the second capture group.
- `.*`  matches zero or more ([`*`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)) of any character that may appear on a line ([`.`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)). In other words, it matches the rest of the line.

Then `$1\L$2` causes all the matched text (the whole line, assuming it *did* match) to be replaced with:

- `$1`, the contents of the first capture group, without modification. This is the field that is intended to contain a person's surname.
- `\L$2`, the contents of the second capture group (`$2`), converted to lower-case ([`\L`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427654/regex-implementation-to-replace-group-with-its-lowercase-version)). This is the first character that is intended to contain a person's given name (but made lower-case).

That may well work for you as-is. But:

- You may need to modify both occurrences of `\w` in the pattern, depending on which characters you wish to match in names. `\w` only matches letters, digits, and the underscore (`_`). Many names have other characters than this, such as dashes and apostrophes.
- There is also the issue of what qualifies as a letter (which applies, albeit sometimes with different solutions, to simpler tools, too). See [What is the best way to match only letters in a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754097/what-is-the-best-way-to-match-only-letters-in-a-regex) This is relevant for names that contain accented letters, diacritic marks that attach to letters, and letters in non-Latin alphabets.
- Case conversion is a harder problem than it may appear. Not only do different written languages have different letters, they also have different case conversions for some of the same letters.

The other very *simple* choice in place of `\w` that I can think of--allowing names to contain anything *other* than whitespace or a `,`--can be achieved by replacing each `\w` with `[^,\S]`. The `[` `]` make a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), the leading `^` means the class contains all *but* the specified characters (which is *not* related to its meaning outside a character class), `,` specifies itself literally, and [`\s`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) specifies all whitespace characters.

```
perl -wpe 's/^([^,\s]+),\s*([^,\s]).*/$1\L$2/' file
```

For more information on regular expressions in Perl, see [`perldoc perlretut`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and [`perldoc perlre`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). The problem you've presented is *just* complex enough to motivate me to use a more sophisticated (and thus more complicated) tool than the basic text processing tools. Since you can probably find a way to do it with those tools, I certainly don't blame you if you do! But I think this may still be helpful for future, even more complex problems.

Comment: thanks for the help is there another way to get the character A in Ashley. like using Cut, Just the character A.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solution with cut, pipes, tr, paste, (and sed) might be:

```
cut -f1 -d, foo >bar; cut -f2 -d" " foo | cut -c1 |tr "A-Z" "a-z" >bar2 ;paste bar bar2|sed -e "s/\x9//g"
```

with foo being the file with your input.
So you can manage the task with cut and others, but the pearl solution is more elegant and appropriate.